# I want to remove padding from left right side in mobile device using bootstrap?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, padding

If I will use overflow hidden then slider will not showing on mobile devices[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txv7O.png)

Answer (score -1):

*RE: I want to remove padding from left right side*

This is the concept. You can change `#item` and put it in the right place in your css.

```
/* mobile first */
#item {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
/* then other screens */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #item {
        padding-right: 25px;  /* or other value */
        padding-left: 25px;   /* or other value */
    }
}
```

Comment: #item is class of slider but padding will come whole the body of mobile device how to solve it?

Comment: Showing the concept is the only way because you did supply only an image without code! A code snippet will be helpful for others to see where sometinging goes wrong.